# Messaging application, Realtime update for message post time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am making messaging application. User1 broadcasts `a message`. To other users I need to show how long back, this message was posted. e.g. Posted 9 min. ago. Quite similar to what we see in `SO` or facebook.

[image]

For this purpose I have started storing message post time, along with message. My plan is to rely on client side clock using javascript to show real time update in the browser.

Is this the way I should go ahead, or there is a better solution out there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [signalR](http://signalr.net/) . It is what you are looking for. And there is also [Jabbr](https://jabbr.net/) built on signalR for chat client.

SignalR supports broadcasting, tries to find out server and client capabilites and use best for case. Supports web sockets, long polling and forever frames etc. If you want to use across multiple servers, it also can use Sql server and Redis as backend.

wiki page : https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki

By the way, SO uses web sockets for real time updates, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129499/what-technology-framework-is-stackoverflow-using-to-asynchronously-update-client

Comment: Thanks! looking into SignalR. For the time being, I will have stick with AJAX calls,  Any pointers in this direction please ?

Comment: with jquery and pooling yes you might do that. but signalr really easy to use library. Wont take your much time to figure it out.

Comment: Do I really need to poll the server. For this scenario, can't we simply rely on client side clock ? Off-course I will have to handle timezone conversion, logic.

Comment: If you just want this functionality. You can use knockoutjs which supports observables you can track changes.  Or simply use a set interval and change labels.